# How to remove all event listeners from certain categories that are mentioned in Chrome Console in Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove all event listeners that are connected to the element that I can see in the Chrome Console in Event Listeners?

jQuery can be used if it will make it easier.

For example:

This is tab in Chrome console.
[image: Chrome Console]

As you can see element is `<a>` but it as also some listeners from `<div>`, there is remove button next to each listener.

I would like to replicate something like this Remove button that deletes all listeners from mouseleave and mouseenter category.

I have tried to use jQuery's `.unbind('mouseleave mouseover')` but it doesn't remove them.

Is there any way how can I access all listeners from one category and remove them?

Comment: Maybe events are attached by jquery on. Did you try jquery.off()? https://api.jquery.com/off

Comment: Try replacing the elements with their own outerHTML. Removing an element removes listeners attached to it. The replacement is a new instance. This will also affect listeners on all of it's children as well

Comment: @muratonnet Unfortunately, some events are from different framework and I just need to overwrite hover functionality. If I add new hover listeners then I end up with multiple hover listeners.

Comment: @charlietfl That's good idea but I still need to keep click listeners from framework in and only replace hover listeners.

Comment: Addition: I really wonder how Chrome Console gets those listeners as it can list all listeners from all categories and each of them can be separately removed.

Comment: You need a reference to the handler function to use `removeEventListener()`. Don't think there is  way to get that. The console has access to things that aren't publicly exposed

Comment: @charlietfl ah, that doesn't sound good. I can make a workaround by overwriting default solution and do a few !important statements in CSS but really hoped for a way to be able to remove them.

Comment: The difference with how jQuery does it is all those handler function are stored internally so you then can remove  with simply the event name

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it with a clone:

```js
const el = document.querySelector(...)
el.parentNode.replaceChild(el.cloneNode(true), el)
```

Then you can reattach the listened you still need if any.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help in my case as I still need to keep some events functionality which comes from different framework. Anyway, this may help some other people with similar problem who don't need part of the previous functionality.